# How to load balancing ASP.NET WebServices using Nginx

Tags: nginx, mono

guys i have tree web services running mono for asp.net

```
 http://1.1.1.1:6789/Service.asmx
 http://1.1.1.2:6789/Service.asmx
 http://1.1.1.3:6789/Service.asmx
```

and i have this on my nginx web servers

```
 upstream wsservices {
 ip_hash;
 server 1.1.1.1:6789;
 server 1.1.1.2:6789;
 server 1.1.1.3:6789;
 }


 server {
 listen 8192;
 error_page 502 503 504 @wsmant;
 location / {
 #proxy_set_header Host $host;
 #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 #proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_pass  http://wsservices;
 }
 location @wsmant {
    root /proxy/www;
    rewrite ^(.*) /wsmant.html break;
 }
 }
```

i can acces to the ws from the nginx but when i hit invoke i get

```
 http://wsservices:8080/Service.asmx/testconnection? net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

and the problem is???? thanks!

Comment: Include logs. Useless without them.

Comment: ok, i add the log parameters access_log and error_log on error is empty and access i get :   - - [30/Jan/2015:18:07:36 -0400] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"